# Selecting an element with placing a custom dataset as the class

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript And facing a little issue,
I hope I will get the solution here

I have a nav Item with a data like this

```
<button data-home="home" class="nav-item"></button>
```

I did select the button element as a var and got its dataset

```
var navI = document.querySelector('.nav-item')

var homeC = navI.dataset
```

And then I wanted to set this item as a class to select a new element

new element,

```
<div class="home"></div>
```

And placed the dataset like this to select the element

```
var pageHome = document.querySelecter('.' + homeC)
```

But pageHome comes with a null element

Pls pass me a solution if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataset` is **the entire data set**, i.e. the result of all `data-*` attributes on the element or properties set via the element data API.

You need to reach into it and get the property you need. In short, change

```
var homeC = navI.dataset
```

to

```
var homeC = navI.dataset.home
```

Also be aware that these days `var` is not recommended; use `let` or `const`.

[EDIT]

Since you know say the home element has the *ID* "home", not the *class* "home", you need:

```
document.querySelector('#'+homeC);
```

Comment: I used it but using querySelector is giving a null element

Comment: Then the element doesn't exist at the time the code runs. Try to reproduce the issue in a Fiddle.

Comment: If I use id = "home" instead of class and write it like this ```var pageName = document.getElementById(homeC) ``` then it works perfectly But how do I make it work with querySelector?

Comment: Huh? You said in your question the home element had the *class* "home", not *ID* "home". See edit.

Comment: I just said if I use Id instead of class it works but I need to make it work with class . I mean querySelector not getElementById.Kindly if you know how to make it work with querySelectors pls let me know

Comment: Ok good. Now I have made it work well with querySelector. Putting that home after dataset has solved it. Thank you so much